# JOIN a la misma tabla por dos campos diferentes

Tags: laravel, eloquent, querybuilder

Estoy trabajando sobre laravel 8, con Eloquent
Tengo una tabla "Principal" con la que le hago join a otra tabla "detalle" para traer el nombre de uno de los campos.

Pero ahora la tabla principal usa dos campos, con los codigos, y tengo que ir a la tabla detalle para traer los nombres de este codigo. para un solo campo no habia problema, pero ahora tengo que hacerlo para los dos campos.

Esta consulta esta bien:

```
$data = Principal::select('falla', 'detalle.nombre as  nombre1','anomalia','medida')
        ->leftJoin('detalle', 'detalle.id' , 'principal.detalle1')
        ->where('principal.id', $request->id)
        ->first();
```

Pero ahora la tabla principal tiene detalle2, y tengo que hacer join con la misma tabla y no he podido hacerlo.
Intenté cosas como estas, pero no me han funcionado:

```
    $data = Principal::select('falla', 'detalle.nombre as  nombre1','anomalia','medida',

                DB::raw(select('detalle.nombre as  nombre2')
                ->leftJoin('detalle', 'detalle.id' , 'principal.detalle2')->first()))

                ->leftJoin('detalle', 'detalle.id' , 'principal.detalle1')
                ->where('principal.id', $request->id)
                ->first();
```

Como podria organizar la consulta para que funcione? en la misma tabla join pero con datos diferentes.
Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Generé un segundo join y le di un alias. con este alias ya pude obtener un segundo dato de la misma tabla.
finalmente me quedó asi el join en eloquent y me funcionó.

```
 $data = Principal::select('falla', 'detalle.nombre as  nombre1','anomalia','medida', 'de.nombre as  nombre2')
                ->leftJoin('detalle', 'detalle.id' , 'principal.detalle1')
                ->leftJoin('detalle as de', 'de.id' , 'principal.detalle2')
                ->where('principal.id', $request->id)
                ->first();
```

Comment: buenas noches tu respuesta es aceptable pero no esta utilizando el 100 de Eloquent: Relationships, le sugiero que lea el siguiente articulo https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships

Answer (score 0):

para esto se recomienda el uso de https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships
que lo traer el propio framework para mejorar las consulta

```
 $data = Principal::with('detalle2_pk','detalle1_pk')->where('principal.id', $request->id)
        ->first();

 return response()->json($data );
```

en tu modelo **Principal** deber añadir la función llamada **detalle1_pk** y **detalle2_pk**  que que tiene dentro de tu with

App\Detalle1 corresponde al modelo relacionado

```
 <?php
    
    namespace App;
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
    class Principal extends Model
    {
        public function detalle1_pk()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo('App\Detalle1');
        }
        public function detalle2_pk()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo('App\Detalle2');
        }
    }
```

y recuerde de crear el modelo de detalle1 y detalle2

```
 <?php
    
    namespace App;
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
    class Detalle1 extends Model
    {
       
    }
 <?php
    
    namespace App;
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
    class Detalle2 extends Model
    {
       
    }
```

a final le va a imprimir

el siguiente resultado

```
{
id:4,
falla:'no',
detalle2_pk:{
   id:4
  },
detalle1_pk:{
  id:5
  }
}
```

y para imprimir el resultado solo tiene que escribir {{ detalle1_pk.id }}